# How to get multiple images from your PC in your android studio's project resource file?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am facing this issue... I have some 4-5 images in PC. I set one of these images as my background in one of the screens of my project... Later on, when I tried to add another image as background of another screen in the same project; the first image disappeared and the new image was automatically added to all the screens... whereas I had expected different images on different screens as background.
Please give me a solution for this problem!
Thankyou

Comment: What do you mean by window?, do you mean background of your activity?

Comment: Screen transitions

Comment: Thats the expected behaviour, try using fragments

Comment: Ohk tysm... I got my solution over here:- https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-add-images-in-android-studio-drawable-folder/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of surfing, I found out [this](http://%20dev2qa.com/how-to-add-images-in-android-studio-drawable-folder), and now everything works cool!

Answer (score 0):

- add images to drawable folder
- set background in XML like

  android:background="@drawable/your_image_name_without_extension"

Or you can add an imageview to show image in background.